# Swift Generic extension doesn't call the proper extension function when generic passed with constraint to a function

Tags: swift, generics, type-erasure

It's a bit hard to explain the problem so I added a working playground code.
But the problem is if I call `provide` on Box directly everything works fine, if I pass box to another function and call provide it doesn't call the proper extension function

```
enum MyEnum: CaseIterable {
    case a
    case b
}

struct Box<T> {
    let value: T
}


extension Box where T: CaseIterable {
    func provide() -> [String]? {
        return T.allCases.map { String(describing: $0) }
    }
}

extension Box where T == Bool {
    func provide() -> [String]? {
        return ["true", "false"]
    }
}

extension Box {
    func provide() -> [String]? {
        return nil
    }
}

protocol Boxable {
    var options: [String]? { get }
}

struct TypeErasedBox: Boxable {
    let options: [String]?

    init<T>(box: Box<T>) {
        self.options = box.provide()
    }
}

extension Box {
    func typeErased() -> Boxable {
        return TypeErasedBox(flag: self)
    }
}

// This works as expected
Box(value: true).provide() // true, false
Box(value: MyEnum.a).provide() // a, b
Box(value: "").provide() // nil

// This doesn't work
Box(value: true).typeErased().options // nil
Box(value: MyEnum.a).typeErased().options // nil
Box(value: "").typeErased().options // nil
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use extensions to implement overloads. But extensions don't work that way in Swift. (There is some thought that some day they might, but that day is not yet here.) The runtime is not going to choose between your extensions based on what some type is.

Comment: but it does work if I call it directly on the generic (Box). Is there a workaround?

Comment: If you need inheritance and overrides, then use classes. But as a rule, you should not try to reinvent class inheritance in structs and protocols. It's not going to work; and even if you find a workaround, it's going to be very fragile and surprising call the wrong code. Do not design your system this way. If you have a concrete problem, we can help you design it in a more appropriate way.

Comment: In your example, what should be called if I conform `Bool` to `CaseIterable`? (There's nothing that stops me from doing that.) This opens up the diamond problem, which is one of many inheritance problems Swift tries to avoid.

Comment: @RobNapier I'm open to other suggestions, I haven't found a solution. Basically I have a ViewController that needs to access an array of Box and get `options` from each box. Options should depend on the type of generics. I really don't have a specific way I want to solve this, I'll be happy with any working solution

Comment: Ask that question and we'll be happy to look at it.

Comment: I suspect part of the problem here, though, is `Boxable` and `TypeErasedBox`. Why do these exist? What is the nature of "Box?" Most importantly, what does the ViewController do with the returned options? Are Options always an array of strings?

Comment: @RobNapier Box is just a featureFlag I'm creating (simplified code with generic names for SO), and I'm building a UI that needs to display them all along with their options. The only reason I have typeErased is because swift doesn't allow an array of generics. and I was not able to solve this by simply placing Box behind a protocol, because then I can't provide custom options for caseIterable

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a generic struct, a protocol, and a type-eraser, start with the thing you really need (the feature flag), and use protocols to adapt it to your UI requirements.

Internally a feature flag needs a value, and that value may be any type (bool, enum, string, number, etc.). But for the UI, it sounds like you just want to display a list of strings and let the user pick from one, and then assign that. So we'll start with a couple of simple FeatureFlags in their internal form:

```
struct BetaFeatureFlag {
    let name = "Enable Beta"
    var enabled: Bool
}

enum APIVersion: String, CaseIterable {
    case v1
    case v2
}

struct APIVersionFlag {
    let name = "API Version"
    var version: APIVersion
}
```

Now we need to think about what the caller (the UI) needs, and model that as a protocol:

```
protocol FeatureFlag: RawRepresentable where RawValue == String {
    var name: String { get }
    var valueNames: [String] { get }
}
```

There are a lot of other ways to do this, but this is one. A FeatureFlag needs a name, a list of possible values as strings, and it need to be possible to read and write that string in a failable way (which RawRepresentable gives us).

With that, we can conform our feature flags to the protocol:

```
extension BetaFeatureFlag: FeatureFlag {
    var valueNames: [String] { ["true", "false"] }

    init?(rawValue: String) {
        switch rawValue {
        case "true": enabled = true
        case "false": enabled = false
        default: return nil
        }
    }
    var rawValue: String { enabled ? "true" : "false" }
}

extension APIVersionFlag: FeatureFlag {
    var valueNames: [String] { APIVersion.allCases.map{$0.rawValue} }

    init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let value = APIVersion(rawValue: rawValue) else { return nil }
        self.version = value
    }
    var rawValue: String { version.rawValue }
}
```

That works, but of course a lot of flags are going to have very similar code. But it's important to stop for a moment and try this out with the view controller and make sure all the parts work. All you need is a `[FeatureFlag]`. No need for type-erasers or associated types or anything complicated. Once we know that this is probably correct with concrete types, we can improve code reusability.

First, we can handle Bool feature flags.

```
protocol BoolFeatureFlag: FeatureFlag {
    init(enabled: Bool)
    var enabled: Bool { get set }
}

extension BoolFeatureFlag {
    var valueNames: [String] { ["true", "false"] }

    init?(rawValue: String) {
        switch rawValue {
        case "true": self.init(enabled: true)
        case "false": self.init(enabled: false)
        default: return nil
        }
    }
    var rawValue: String { enabled ? "true" : "false" }
}
```

And then BetaFeatureFlag just has to conform to BoolFeatureFlag and it's done:

```
struct BetaFeatureFlag: BoolFeatureFlag {
    let name = "Enable Beta"
    var enabled: Bool
}
```

Similarly, we can haul most of the APIVersionFeatureFlag code into an EnumFeatureFlag for reusability:

```
protocol EnumFeatureFlag: FeatureFlag {
    associatedtype Value: CaseIterable, RawRepresentable where Value.RawValue == RawValue
    var value: Value { get }
    init(value: Value)
}

extension EnumFeatureFlag {
    var valueNames: [String] { Value.allCases.map{$0.rawValue} }

    init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let value = Value(rawValue: rawValue) else { return nil }
        self.init(value: value)
    }
    var rawValue: String { value.rawValue }
}
```

And then APIVersion just needs to conform to this reusable protocol:

```
struct APIVersionFlag: EnumFeatureFlag {
    let name = "API Version"
    var value: APIVersion
}
```

Notice the differences between FeatureFlag and BoolFeatureFlag/EnumFeatureFlag. FeatureFlag is intended for being held in an array, and it flattens everything into Strings so that there's no need for associated types. Below that, Bool/EnumFeatureFlag are intended for reusing code. They're not really expected to be in an array or a property type or anything like that. So it's fine that EnumFeatureFlag has an associated type.

Comment: Thanks for the effort on this answer, looks great. Will try to add Codable support and if it works well I'll go with this instead of use of generics